# Redirecting user if record isn't in database

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I have a URL shortener script that makes the user provide the record ID then redirects them. However, **I want to be able to redirect the user to a specific page if the record they searched for does not exist**. How can I do this?

My current code is:

```
<?

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$sql="select * from shortened where (shortened.id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url'])."')";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
header('Location:'.$row['url']);
}

?>
```

I hope people can understand what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: Guys, please, at least here - don't mention PDO and placeholders, for god's sake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit;
}
```

right before your `while` part

And your `while` could be actually rewritten as:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
header('Location:'.$row['url']);
```

(yes, just remove `while` - it is pointless in this case)

Comment: shouldn't it be `if(!mysql_num_rows($query))` , or am I missing something? This way if the function returns 0 / false, the if condition evaluates to true

Comment: @xbonez: yes it should be, fixed. Just a typo made by programming in browser. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$sql="select * from shortened where (shortened.id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url'])."')";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)

header('Location:'.$row['url']);


?>
```

while loop is no necessary here

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<? 
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$sql="select * from shortened where (shortened.id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url'])."')";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $url = $row['url'];
} else {
        $url = "http://othersite.com";

}
header("Location: $url");

?>
```

Comment: +1 - solves the problem and introduces some optimisation (though it's possible to only call `header` once...)

Comment: It's important to put `exit;` after the redirect, otherwise the rest of the code will execute on the server. That's something you learn the hard way =/